# Laravel Auth with different connection for each subdomain?

Tags: laravel, authentication, database-connection, subdomain

I'm building an app where each subdomain has its own database.
For example:
**"example1.app.dev"** uses **"example1_dbo"** database
**"example2.app.dev"** uses **"example2_dbo"** database

Each subdomain has its own users, meaning that for example:
*user_ex1* can only login on *example1.app.dev* because he is set in *example1_dbo* 
*user_ex2* can only login on *example2.app.dev* because he is set in *example2_dbo*

How do I achieve this with Laravel Auth?
Basicaly I have set subdomain routing:

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.dev')->group(function () {})
```

And i have set up database connections in config/database.php and env file.
I have used this concept on Eloquent models with `Model->setConnection($account)`
But this method is exhausting while app is growing...

I'm looking for Middleware solution where i can change default DB connection for request globally and for Auth as well while i was not able to get authentication to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this package:
https://github.com/stancl/tenancy

It provide that out of the box.
hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful. I've read the docs and admire the concept.

I've ended up with a middleware similar to the Tenant concept in which I change default dbo conn and locale. Works like a charm.